# Android - Cannot resolve symbol Toast

Tags: java, android

This happens alot to me... I often find code on SO but users do not add the necessary imports.

I get `Cannot resolve symbol Toast`

I searched the documentation of toast, but I am unable to find the necessary import line. I tried `import ui.notifiers.toasts` because it is in the URL, but does not work.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts

Comment: @MichaelDodd, I pressed alt + Enter, but it just asked me if it should create a new class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
import android.widget.Toast;
```

Comment: Is there an echo?

Comment: @NehaRathore what is your comment for?